# Punctuation with "and thus" in the middle of a sentence

Tags: punctuation

I was wondering if I have to place a comma before and after "and thus". Usually, this is followed by a comma, but in this sentence, I think one comma before it is enough. Right?

> "accepted theories can provide satisfactory results, and thus, experiments can be avoided."

Comment: "accepted theories can provide satisfactory results, and, thus, experiments can be avoided."

Answer (score 18):

This sentence has two independent clauses. They are connected by "and" with a comma before it. The "and" and the comma are correct. However, adding a comma after "thus" is not correct because it is an adverb; the comma after it is not necessary.

The sentence is fine this way:

> "Accepted theories can provide satisfactory results, and thus experiments can be avoided."

If "thus" is used as a conjunctive adverb (without "and"), a semi-colon and a comma are necessary. This version of your sentence is also correct:

> "Accepted theories can provide satisfactory results; thus, experiments can be avoided."

Both of these sentences are clearer than your sentence that has the comma after "thus."

Comment: One need not use a comma for every break either when reading or verbalizing. The only problem with your answer is that a comma *may* be used after "thus," but it's not necessary.

Comment: @StuW--A comma after "thus" would trigger a comma after "and" because  it joins two clauses:  " . . . .can provide satisfactory results, and, thus, experiments can be avoided."  This also shows that "thus" is unnecessary: ". . . .can provide satisfactory results, and experiments can be avoided. "Thus" means "therefore" in this context; "thus" emphasizes that the second condition (avoiding experiments) occurs when the first condition (relying on accepted theories) exists.

Comment: Is it necessary to have the comma before and?